# How do I launch Everpad?

Tags: python, software-installation, pyside, everpad

### The Problem:

Unable to launch Everpad on 64bit Ubuntu 13.10. I get the below error:

```
$ everpad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/everpad", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('everpad==2.6.1dev', 'gui_scripts', 'everpad')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point    
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2321, in load_entry_point
    return ep_map
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2048, in load
    if req.specs: raise ValueError
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/pad/indicator.py", line 8, in <module>
    from everpad.pad.editor import Editor
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/pad/editor/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from everpad.interface.editor import Ui_Editor
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/interface/editor.py", line 125, in <module>
    from PySide import QtWebKit
ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit
```

### What I have tried so far:

Interestingly, I tried testing Everpad in a live boot and still had the same issue. The latest repositories just do not like the PySide module.

I did have an issue beforehand where it failed because it couldn't even see the PySide module in Python. However I managed to work around the PySide install and got to the latest error of not being able to import QtWebKit from PySide. I have found the below link which managed to get me to this stage.

https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/401

Thought the issue could be to do with the PySide install not having the .egg-info. Apparently something to do with the way apt-get installs python-pyside. However it doesn't seem to install the PySide.QTWebKit module correctly. Also get this problem from `pip install pyside`. The link above pretty much just suggests installing PySide via `pip install pyside` but I seem to have problems directly with importing QTWebKit from the PySide module in the python interpreter.

### Other things I have tried:

I have tried linking from the QtWebKit that I found in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide but that just resulted in a 'Segmentation failure' when launching Everpad.

Anyone that understands the PySide module/Python/Everpad able to shed some light on this one? Is it my PySide module just not installing correctly?